# How to call a GET API with string parameter after I login and passing the email address so the data will come out? (REACT.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, fetch-api

I need to call a GET API with string parameter after login, so the user detail will be shown out. The API I done is GET API with string parameters of email.

The API result as shown below:

[image]

I need to call the API with the path variables of email to get the detail.

```
class Home extends Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state ={
    loginEmail: this.props.location.state.loginEmail,
    isLoaded: false,
    redirect: false
  }
  this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount(){
  fetch('https://ems-unimas-58134.herokuapp.com/api/users/view/${email}')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.state({
      isLoaded: true,
      
    })
  });
}
```

I am not sure is it the correct way I do in `componentDidMount`. By the way, is it any other method that can call the API automatically after I login to the Home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other way can be .........you can call this api after success response of  your login api . I mean

```
fetch('url to login').then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
fetch('https://ems-unimas-58134.herokuapp.com/api/users/view/${email}')....
    )
```